# Custom marker in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I have a matplotlib script for drawing several lines showing the results for 8, 16, 32, and 64 bit configurations. The figure is a bit crowded and in order to make it easier to read I would like to add these number as markers. Also I prefer to have a circle around the text. This means that the marker will be a text with a surrounding circle.

My code is like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.ticker as mtick
import numpy as np

# Turn off DISPLAY
#matplotlib.use('Agg')
import pylab

fig = plt.figure()
ax = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)

# T = 16
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(18.25,15.5,14.15,14.07), linestyle='--', lw=2, marker="D", markersize=7, color='r', label="Stepped Parity 16-bit");
# T = 32
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(11.90,10.29,9.23,9.11), linestyle='--', lw=2, marker="*", markersize=10, color='r', label="Stepped Parity 32-bit");
# T = 64
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(6.64,6.20,5.53,5.39), linestyle='--', lw=2, marker="H", markersize=8, color='r', label="Stepped Parity 64-bit");

# T = 16
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(25.52,22.51,21.05,21.02), linestyle='-', lw=2, marker="D", markersize=7, color='b', label="Interleaving 16-bit");
# T = 32
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(17.18, 15.13, 13.56, 13.51), linestyle='-', lw=2, marker="*", markersize=10, color='b', label="Interleaving 32-bit");
# T = 64
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(8.84, 8.31, 7.97, 7.91), linestyle='-', lw=2, marker="h", markersize=8, color='b', label="Interleaving 64-bit");

plt.xlim([0.75, 4.25])
plt.ylim([0, 30])

plt.xticks([1,2,3,4],[512, 1024, 2048, 4096], fontsize=14)
plt.yticks(fontsize=14)

plt.xlabel('# of Words', fontsize=16)
plt.ylabel('Area Overhead', fontsize=16)

# Percentage sign in Y-axis
fmt = '%.0f%%' # Format you want the ticks, e.g. '40%'
yticks = mtick.FormatStrFormatter(fmt)
ax.yaxis.set_major_formatter(yticks)  

plt.legend(ncol=2)

# Save in PDF file
pylab.savefig("Output.pdf", dpi=400, bbox_inches='tight', pad_inches=0.05)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can have all the kinky latex as your markers you want, including text. It will probably end up looking really bad though...
But at least now you have a [wider arrangement](http://web.ift.uib.no/Teori/KURS/WRK/TeX/symALL.html) of symbols to choose from.

```
plt.plot((1,2,3,4),(11.90,10.29,9.23,9.11), linestyle='--',
         lw=2, marker="$32$", markersize=17, color='r',
         label="Stepped Parity 32-bit")
```

Just make sure they're sent inside the `"$ $"` tags as [described in the manual](http://matplotlib.org/api/markers_api.html).

Python 3 matplotlib 1.3.1 Win7 tested. Also please wrap your lines at 65 char length. It's just so much more comfortable to read.